# Multithreaded chat in windows C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, server, client, chat

I'm trying to do a simple multithreaded client/server chat but I have a problem, the program go in a loop without show any message, all I have is the message "Received: " and nothing more.
Here the codes
Server code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.lib") // link with Ws2_32.lib
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT 54345

using namespace std;

void *receive(void *)
{
    SOCKET client;
    long app;
    char buff[256];
    memset(&buff,0,sizeof(buff));
    while(1)
   {
        memset(&buff,0,sizeof(buff));
        app=recv(client,buff,sizeof(buff), 0);
        if(app<0) cout<<" Can't get message"<<endl;
        else cout<<"Client: "<<buff<<endl;  
    }
}

int main() 
{
    pthread_t threadA[5];
    cout<<"Server TCP/IP"<<endl; 
    char recvbuf[256]; //buff ti get message
    char serverAddrStr[256]={'\0'}; //Contain the IP address
   #ifdef WIN32       
   WSADATA wsaData;
   WSAStartup (0x0101,&wsaData);
   #endif
   long res; 
   WSADATA wsadata; 
   res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &wsadata); //Initialize winsock
   if(res==0) cout<<"Winsocket initialized!"<<endl;   
   else cout<<"Error initializing winsocket"<<endl;
   SOCKET slisten,client; //Socket Descriptor
   cout<<"IP address to connect: ";
   cin.getline(serverAddrStr,256);
   slisten=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); 
   if(slisten!=INVALID_SOCKET) cout<<"Socket created!"<<endl;
   else cout<<"Error creating socket"<<endl;
   //info of the socket
   sockaddr_in info; //sockaddr
   info.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY; //accept anyone
   info.sin_family=AF_INET; 
   info.sin_port=htons(54345); //Convert the porta in the order (big-endian) of TCP/IP 
   int infolen=sizeof(info); //Contain dimension ofsockaddr
   res=bind(slisten,(struct sockaddr*)&info, infolen); 
   if(res!=SOCKET_ERROR) cout<<"Connessione estabilished!"<<endl; 
   else cout<<"Connection error..."<<endl;
   res=listen(slisten,SOMAXCONN); 
   if(res!=SOCKET_ERROR) cout<<"I'm on the port 54345"<<endl; 
   else cout<<"Can't listen on port 54345"<<endl;
   sockaddr_in clientinfo; //Info of the client
   int clientinfolen=sizeof(clientinfo); 
int nthread=0;
   while(nthread<5) 
   {
       clientinfolen= sizeof(clientinfo);
       cout<<"I'm waiting a client"<<endl;
       client=accept(slisten,(struct sockaddr*)&clientinfo,&clientinfolen); 
       if(client<0) 
       {
           cout<<"Can't accept connection"<<endl;
           return 0;
       }
       cout<<"Connection estabilished"<<endl;
       res=pthread_create(&threadA[nthread],NULL,receive,NULL);
       if(res!=0) cout<<"Error creating thread"<<endl;
       nthread++;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++) pthread_join(threadA[i],NULL);
   closesocket(client); 
   closesocket(slisten); 
   WSACleanup(); 

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

And here the client code:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
     cout<<"Client TCP/IP"<<endl;
     char sendbuf[256]; //Buffer to send
     long res; 
     WSADATA wsadata; 
     SOCKET sConnect; 
     sockaddr_in conpar;
     res=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&wsadata); 
     if(res==0) cout<<"Winsock initialized!"<<endl; 
     else cout<<"Winsock initializing failed"<<endl;
     sConnect=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); //Create the socket
     if(sConnect!=INVALID_SOCKET) cout<<"Socket created!"<<endl; 
     else cout<<"Errore creating socket, error: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
     hostent *serverInfo; //Info of the host
     char serverAddrStr[256]; //IP address
     cout<<"IP address: ";
     cin.getline(serverAddrStr,256); 

     conpar.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr(serverAddrStr); //IP address to connect
     conpar.sin_family=AF_INET; 
     conpar.sin_port=htons(54345); //Port to connect in big endian format
     int conparlen=sizeof(conpar); 
     res=connect(sConnect,(struct sockaddr*)&conpar,conparlen); //Connection
     if(res!=SOCKET_ERROR) cout<<"Connessione estabilished!"<<endl; 
     else cout<<"Connection failed, error: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
     while(1) 
     {
         memset(&sendbuf,0,sizeof(sendbuf)); 
         cout<<"Send: ";
         cin.getline(sendbuf,256);; //Get message
         res=send(sConnect,sendbuf,strlen(sendbuf),0); 
     }
     closesocket(sConnect); 
     WSACleanup(); 

     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
 }
```

I'm using posix thread in windows system with the package installated.

Comment: Oh my... That code is unreadable, it's just an undecipherable wall of noise! Please add some spacing and newlines in there. The comments in Italian(?) doesn't help much either, at least not for us who don't understand Italian (which is most of the people here).

Comment: Sorry my bad, i translated the codes :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `receive` function never sets `client` to a sensible value. You have a lot of other issues, but that's the most obvious.

```
void *receive(void *)
{
    SOCKET client; // ** Create variable
    long app;
    char buff[256];
    memset(&buff,0,sizeof(buff));
    while(1)
    {
        memset(&buff,0,sizeof(buff));
        app=recv(client,buff,sizeof(buff), 0); // ** Use variable
        if(app<0) cout<<" Can't get message"<<endl;
        else cout<<"Client: "<<buff<<endl;  
    }
}
```

Where is it set to a sensible value?

You also seem to have the mistaken understanding that calling `recv` on a TCP connection will receive a message. That's not true. If you want a function that receives a message, you have to write one.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean for sensibile value

Comment: I mean a value that corresponds to an actual connection. You never set it at all. Check out my updates.

Comment: Which type of variabile i have to use? And how i should use it?